# Print text inputted in a php form

Tags: php, fpdf

I put an input text in my form and when I click print it should print in the pdf the text I input in that text field following the table form format. I have a problem on how to catch data from the php file.
PFDF Here is my code:

```
<?php 

$html = <<<MYTABLE 

<table border="1" style="width:90%" title="Leave" cellpadding="5px" align="center"> 
<tr> 
<td rowspan=1 width="70" align:"top-left"><center><b>1. Office/Agency</b>    </center><br><select name="office_agency"></td> 
<td rowspan=1 width="100" colspan="2" align:"top-left"><b>2. ID&nbsp;&nbsp; / &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Name</b><br> </td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td rowspan=1 align:"top-left"><b>3. Date of Filing:</b><br></td> 
<td rowspan=1 align:"top-left"><b>4. Position</b><br></td> 
<td rowspan=1 align:"top-left"><b>4. Salary</b><br></td>
```

..........

```
MYTABLE; 
require('pdftable.inc.php'); 

mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); 
mysql_select_db('auth'); 

$p = new PDFTable(); 
$p->AddPage(); 
$p->setfont('times','',10); 
$p->Cell(5,-5,' APPLICATION FOR LEAVE'); 
$p->Ln(3); 
$p->htmltable($html); 
$p->output(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the content to the page using Write()

```
$pdf->Write("content here");
```

[Write Documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/write.htm)